# Git Equivalent of 'repo start --head XXXX'

Tags: git, repo

Let's say that I have a git branch `featureA` and I want to create a new branch with `HEAD/featureA` as the base. Using `repo start --head featureB` while being in the `featureA` branch would accomplish this but how could I do this with `git`? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`repo start --head featureB` creates a branch `featureB` based on `HEAD` and then the new branch is checked out. It's equivalent to `git checkout -b featureB HEAD` or `git switch -c featureB HEAD`. `HEAD` can be omitted.

Comment: Thank you. What do you mean by `HEAD` can be omitted though?

Comment: `git checkout -b featureB` or `git switch -c featureB`.